# Argo Workflow error when using envFrom field

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

Workflow:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: my-workflow-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: configmap
        value: my-configmap
      - name: secret
        value: my-secret
  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
        - - name: main
            templateRef:
              name: my-template
              template: main
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: configmap
                  value: "{{workflow.parameters.configmap}}"
                - name: secret
                  value: "{{workflow.parameters.secret}}"
```

Template:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: my-template
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: configmap
        parameters:
          - name: secret
      container:
        image: my-image:1.2.3
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
            name: "{{inputs.parameters.configmap}}"
          - secretRef:
            name: "{{inputs.parameters.secret}}"
```

When deployed through the Argo UI I receive the following error from Kubernetes when starting the pod:

```
spec.containers[1].envFrom: Invalid value: \"\": must specify one of: `configMapRef` or `secretRef`
```

Using `envFrom` is supported and documented in the Argo documentation: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/fields/. Why is Kubernetes complaining here?

Comment: two problems i think can be there, 1. indentation, 2. the parsing of values, you can probably try hardcoding the names of configMapRef and secretRef , if works then the problem is with parsing, or else try changing indentation,   envFrom definitely supported, its the value at the end causing issue.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty Thanks. I have tried hardcoding the configMapRef and secretRef names and I get the same error. I have also run both YAML through `yamllint` to validate the syntax.

Comment: In your `WorkflowTemplate` object, under `envFrom` : `name` should be **under** `configMapRef` or `secretRef`, not as the same level. `yamllint` does not throw any error because this is still valid yaml, but this is not valid for Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are a couple issues with your manifests. They're valid YAML, but that YAML does not deserialize into valid Argo custom resources.

1. In the Workflow, you have duplicated the `parameters` key in `spec.templates[0].inputs`.
2. In the WorkflowTemplate, you have placed the `configMapRef` and `secretRef` names at the same level as the keys. `configMapRef` and `secretRef` are objects, so the `name` key should be nested under each of those.

These are the corrected manifests:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: my-template
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: configmap
          - name: secret
      container:
        image: my-image:1.2.3
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: "{{inputs.parameters.configmap}}"
          - secretRef:
              name: "{{inputs.parameters.secret}}"

---

apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: my-workflow-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: configmap
        value: my-configmap
      - name: secret
        value: my-secret
  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
        - - name: main
            templateRef:
              name: my-template
              template: main
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: configmap
                  value: "{{workflow.parameters.configmap}}"
                - name: secret
                  value: "{{workflow.parameters.secret}}"
```

Argo Workflows supports [IDE-based validation](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/ide-setup.md) which should help you find/avoid these issues.